# Understanding risk-free discounting with fractional powers

Tags: discounting, risk-free, cash

#### Introduction

Discounting a value $X_{T}$ is premised through the presence of a risk-free security with a rate of $r$ per annum that yields the same value at time $T$, in years. That is

\begin{align*}
P(1+r)^{T} &= X_{T} \\ \\
\implies P &= \frac{X_{T}}{(1+r)^{T}}
\end{align*}

$P$ is the present value of $X_{T}$ and is the convention for discounting cash flows.

#### Understood Examples

Let $T=1$: Then

\begin{align}
P(1+r)^1 &= X_{1}
\end{align}

represents investing $P$ in a risk-free security compounding interest over a single year, yielding $X_{1}$

Let $T=2$: Then

\begin{align}
P(1+r)^2 &= X_{2}
\end{align}

represents investing $P$ in a risk-free security compounding interest every year for 2 years, yielding $X_{2}$

#### Misunderstood Examples

Now let $T=1.5$, or a year and 1-half: Then

\begin{align}
P(1+r)^{1.5} &= X_{1.5} \\ \\
P(1+r)(1+r)^{0.5} &= X_{1.5}
\end{align}

represents investing $P$ into a risk-free security for a year, compounding the interest - though then compounding $P(1+r)$ over a half-year. This doesn't make sense to me as one cannot expand into $(1+r)^{0.5}$. What is the assumption here? In practice, if I wanted to exit out of the security - then wouldn't the final value be

\begin{align}
P(1+r)\left(1+\frac{180r}{360}\right),
\end{align}
where half a year worth of interest is accumulated?

Another point of confusion is the compounding period? Why is it assumed that the risk-free security compounds interest yearly? Why doesn't it compound half-yearly or quarterly? Surely we'd follow the guidelines of say U.S. treasuries, which pays every 6 months. Therefore, I'd re-invest 6-months worth of interest into U.S. treasuries and continue the the process. Though then the discounting equation should be

\begin{align}
P\left(1+\frac{r}{2}\right)^{2T} &= X_{T} \\ \\
\implies P &= \frac{X_{T}}{\left(1+\frac{r}{2}\right)^{2T}}
\end{align}

#### Conclusion

I'm looking for an understanding into my misunderstood examples, and the precise assumptions behind risk-free discounting.

Comment: $(1+R)^t=\exp[\log[(1+R)^t]]=e^{rt}$ where $r=\log(1+R)$. And this is how things are done in continuous time finance.

Comment: Hi @nbbo2 - thank you - that makes sense. Although, in traditional investment banking, with say, a vanilla loan - we aren't working in log or continuous space, right? Any thoughts on this with the asked question?

Comment: You are right both ways. In one formulation the rate is know as a **compound** rate and in the other the rate is known as the **simple** rate. For a fractional period the simple rate is **not** equal to the compound rate, but rounded to a whole period it is. As @nbbo2 states using the continuously compounded rate is another another option. These "rates" describing the same discount factor may all be different based on the definitions of their calculation convention. Sometimes it is easier to work with equations in one form over another.

Comment: @Attack68. Thank you -  the explanation that the two are equal for $T\in\mathbb{Z}$ is great. The cases where $T$ is not an integer confuses me. Purely, from the point of practice (think about purely owning a risk-free security in U.S. treasuries) - why is $$\left(1+r\right)^{0.5}$$ accepted? I remain looking for an answer on its explanation in the real market. In other words - assume holding a security and being told the value after a half-year is $$P\left(1+r\right)^{0.5}$$ and not $$P\left(1+0.5r\right).$$ The latter is what makes sense to me, the former - not.

Comment: You are missing the point. The $r$ in your 1st equation is not the same as the $r$ in the 2nd eqn. In the real world $P(1+r_1)^{0.5}=P(1+0.5r_2)=\frac{P}{1-0.5r_3}$ where $r_1$ is a compounded rate, $r_2$ is a simple rate and $r_3$ is a discount rate. The instrument that references these types of rate might be a a bond yield-to-maturity for $r_1$, an IRS period for $r_2$ or a bill for $r_3$. It not really a question of which one makes sense, they all make sense under the mathematical construct in which they are defined, including continuously compounded rates which are a 4th type.

Comment: I see. This now opens up a new conversation about the rates provided and understanding "(the) mathematical construct in which they are defined." If I'm told that the SOFR Swap Rate is 5% with interest accruing daily, and I charge a risk premium on a risky project finance deal of 5% - then the interest charged on the debt $D$, over half-year is $$\frac{1}{2}10\%D,$$. However, its definition means I cannot use the same SOFR rate for discounting in $$(1+5\%)^{-0.5}.$$ Has my understanding improved? In real deals that I'm seeing - they are being used interchangeably- and this has confused me.